# Python throws arithmetic error in an O(1) solution

Tags: python, math

I am working on the growingPlant problem on code signals.  The problem is very straight forward.  I am to measure how many days it takes for a plant to reach a given desired height.  The plant starts at seed, which is 0.  It has an up speed and a down speed I have to account for.  Its very straight forward and so I decided to use a while loop for it.

Here is the problem description:

```
Caring for a plant can be hard work, but since you tend to it regularly, you have a plant that grows consistently. Each day, its height increases by a fixed amount represented by the integer upSpeed. But due to lack of sunlight, the plant decreases in height every night, by an amount represented by downSpeed.

Since you grew the plant from a seed, it started at height 0 initially. Given an integer desiredHeight, your task is to find how many days it'll take for the plant to reach this height.

Example

For upSpeed = 100, downSpeed = 10, and desiredHeight = 910, the output should be
growingPlant(upSpeed, downSpeed, desiredHeight) = 10.

#   Day Night
1   100 90
2   190 180
3   280 270
4   370 360
5   460 450
6   550 540
7   640 630
8   730 720
9   820 810
10  910 900

The plant first reaches a height of 910 on day 10.
```

Below is my attempt:

```
def growingPlant(upSpeed, downSpeed, desiredHeight):
    days = 0
    height = 0
    
    while height < desiredHeight :
        height += (upSpeed - downSpeed)
        days += 1
        print(height)
    
    return days-1
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for some reason.  For example, it miscalculates the days on the following testcase:

```
upSpeed: 6
downSpeed: 5
desiredHeight: 10

Output: 9

Expected Output: 5

Console Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think more simple.

you should **desiredHeight - upSpeed**

```py
def growingPlant(upSpeed, downSpeed, desiredHeight):
    days = 0
    height = 0
 
    while height < desiredHeight - upSpeed :
        height += (upSpeed - downSpeed)
        days += 1
        print(height)
    
    return days+1
```

because before night comes, it will reach the **desiredHeight**.
So you should write while loop until **desiredHeight** - **upSpeed**.

Even more simple you should just divide with it. Like this.

```py
def growingPlant(upSpeed, downSpeed, desiredHeight):
    nights = (desiredHeight-upSpeed) // (upSpeed - downSpeed) + 1
return nights
```

Answer (score 0):

The plant grows during the day, and shrinks at night.  If the plant reaches the desired height during the day, then you're done.

In other words, you need to add upSpeed and check the height before you subtract downSpeed.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the plant might reach the desired height after it grows for the day, or after it recedes for the day. You only check if it has reached the desired height after it recedes.